# Opening Jquery fancybox from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I can't seem to find the answer to this question anywhere so I ask here.
I already use successfully fancybox like this:

```
$("#editor").fancybox({
            'width' : 1000,
            'height' : 600,
            'autoDimensions' : false,
            'autoScale' : false,
            'ajax' : {
                type : "POST",
                data : varstring
            }
        })
```

Now the problem is that due to new necessities the varstring must contain unique data for each of the link that should open the fancybox window.
Tha way I was picturing it is like this:

```
function openEditor(elementid,sid,pid,gid){
    $("#"+elementid).fancybox({
            'width' : 1000,
            'height' : 600,
            'autoDimensions' : false,
            'autoScale' : false,
            'ajax' : {
                type : "POST",
                data : 'varstringnotimplemented'
            }
        });
    //$("#"+elementid).trigger('click');
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't work, if I uncomment the trigger I get a:

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

Even if I manage to get this thing working is pretty ugly, is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Do `alert(elementid)` in its place, I think you'll find it's empty.

Comment: No need to quote your object keys (this isn't JSON). It's also good practice to choose one type of quote (single or double) and be consistent, rather than mix-and-match as you're doing here.

Comment: @Nick it's not empty.
@Matt I usually only use single quotes, I copypasted from various examples for testing purposes.  About the object keys: thanks I didn't knew this :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to pass the actual object instead of an id.

```
function openEditor(element,sid,pid,gid){
    var $element = $(element);
    var dataString = '??';
    var ajaxSettings = {
                type : "POST",
                data : dataString
            };

    $element.fancybox({
            'width' : 1000,
            'height' : 600,
            'autoDimensions' : false,
            'autoScale' : false,
            'ajax' : ajaxSettings 
        });
    $element.trigger('click');
    return false;
}
```

link would be

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openEditor(this,'some','other','params')">text</a>
```

you cannot pass the actual object if you send it trough the href, you can send it through the onclick

Comment: How do you pass the actual object from the href?

Comment: See the addition in the answer.